# Not Able to Insert JSON Object in Array in Postgresql

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, backend

```
userPool.query('INSERT INTO tweets(tweet_user_id , user_tweets) VALUES($1 , "{"tweet_uid": $2 , "tweet_content": $3 ,"type_of": $4 }")' , [user_uid , tweet_id , content , 'by_user'  ]
```

I am trying to insert json object in an array but i am getting this error:-
[This is The error][image: 1]

And just a small message i have tried pretty much all methods Given on stackoverflow but still not able to solve it

Comment: Try replacing "{ with \'{ and likewise }" with }\'

Comment: also you have mentioned two columns in your insert statement and you are passing 4 values

Comment: Well user_tweets is an array and i want to insert a json object which have 3 values\

Comment: @BjarniRagnarsson I tried Your method but i am getting this error:- malformed array literal: "{"tweet_uid": $2 , "tweet_content": $3 ,"type_of": $4 }"

Comment: Well.  This sure is a malformed array.  Strange not to see the apostropes change.  For this to become a legal array it needs to be enclosed in '    ' but not "   ".  Sorry - I don't have setup to try this out.